# How to set container_name in docker-compose for swarm deployment?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I deploy my docker containers with `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml my-service`

Problem: `docker service ls` shows the `NAME` always with `my-service_my-service`, generated from docker-compose:

```
services:
  my-service:
    #container_name #not supported when using 'docker stack deploy'
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"
    ...
```

This is due to the fact that the name in *docker stack deploy* is taken as stack name, and the service form docker-compose as service name.

Thus, the resulting name is `stackname_servicename`.

Question: how can I force the service being named without a stack prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's not possible to work around that, maybe best would be to give the application only a generic service name, like `app:`.

```
services:
  app:
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"
    ...
```

This way, `docker stack deploy my-service` would result in `my-service_app`. Which reads way better.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is a technical prerequisite, so it is not possible to change. You may change the stackname and the servicename but not the composition of both. The name has to be individual, if not you might have different services in different networks with the same name and therefore ID and alias.

You may build your own "compose" by creating a bash-script with `docker service create --name` to reach that goal, then it is in your own responsibility.